# Welchen Fall verwendet man mit Präposition "ohne"?

Tags: grammar, preposition, grammatical-case

Ich habe bemerkt, dass man bei uns zwar **ohne dich** (seltener und vermutlich falsch auch **ohne dir**) sagt, allerdings wird es mit Nomen anscheinend in Dativ formuliert, also z. B. **ohne der Sache**. Gibt es da eine grammatische Regel die das steuert, oder ist es nur Dialekt ?

Comment: `Ohne dich` aber interessanter Weise `mit dir`

Comment: Sagt man dann "ohne schlechtes Gewissen"? Ich hätte schwören können man sagt "ohne schlechtem Gewissen" - aber das wäre ja Dativ und ist demnach falsch?

Comment: @Jasmin Ja, es heißt *ohne schlechtes Gewissen*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Nach heute gültigen Grammatikregeln verlangt *"ohne"* als [Präposition den Akkusativ](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ohne_Praeposition).

> ohne mich
>   ohne Mühe
>   ohne ihr Zutun

Allerdings beschreibt das [Etymologische Wörterbuch nach Pfeifer](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=ohne) die frühere Verwendung auch mit Genitiv und mit Dativ:

> In präpositionaler Verwendung verlangt ohne, das seit dem Ahd. sowohl ‘nicht versehen mit’ als auch ‘außer, ausgenommen’ sein kann, von Anfang an den Akk., doch ist in älterer Zeit Verknüpfung mit dem Gen. (bei fließendem Übergang zum Adverb) und mit dem Dat. ebenfalls möglich.

Es ist also durchaus möglich, dass im Dialekt oder regional noch die veraltete Verwendung erhalten blieb, ohne dass dies allgemein richtig wäre (*Anm.:* Verwendung von *ohne* hier als Konjunktion).

Wird *"ohne"* als [Konjunktion](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ohne_Konjunktion) eingesetzt, sind natürlich auch Kombinationen wie "*ohne dich"* und "*ohne dir"* möglich:

> Wir sind anderer Meinung, **ohne dir** damit Unrecht zu geben.
>   Diese Aussage ist falsch, **ohne dich** damit verletzen zu wollen.

Comment: Die Formulierung "im Dialekt erhalten ... ohne dass dies allgemein richtig wäre" finde ich problematisch. Dialekte haben eigene Regeln, die innerhalb dieses Dialekts gültig und "richtig" sind. Die Hochsprache ist nur eine Verkehrssprache und beansprucht im privaten Gebrauch keine Vormachtstellung. Im Dialekt ist, was in der Hochsprache gebräuchlich ist, durchaus ungebräuchlich und wird als "falsch" empfunden. Dasselbe gilt für Soziolekte und Fachsprachen.

Answer (score 9):

Das Wort "ohne" steht grundsätzlich mit Akkusativ: Ohne wen? Ohne dich. Somit ist "ohne dir" und "ohne der Sache" falsch.

Diese Konstruktionen existieren allerdings in Fällen, in denen "ohne" sich auf ein Verb bezieht (also nicht auf ein Substantiv, das ja im Akkusativ stehen müsste) und um ein Dativobjekt erweitert wird:

- Ohne dir Schaden zuzufügen ... ("ohne" + Dativobjekt + Akkusativobjekt + Infinitiv)
- Ohne der Sache im Weg zu stehen ... ("ohne" + Dativobjekt + erweiterter Infinitiv).

Ein Nomen nach "ohne" steht also *immer* mit Akkusativ, wenn sich das "ohne" auch auf das entsprechende Nomen beziehen soll. Die Verwendung des Dativs ist entweder somit eine Dialektform oder grammatikalisch falsch.