# In welchen Gebieten ist ohne + Dativ (bzw. nur "ohne dem") gängig?

Tags: phrase, dialect, colloquial, history

Als ich zum ersten Mal [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/18982/3407) gelesen habe, dachte ich es wäre einfach ungrammatisch `ohne` mit dem Dativ zu verwenden. Ich habe also danach gefragt, ob die Person, die meinte, das sei richtig, Muttersprachler ist.

In [einer Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/19002/3407) wurde darauf hingewiesen, dass die Wendung

> ohne dem geht gar nichts

sogar in Büchern steht. Das hat mich dazu geführt, die Wendung zu googeln.

Hier die Ergebnisse:

["ohne dem geht nichts"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ohne%20dem%20geht%20nichts%22)

["ohne dem geht * nichts"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ohne%20dem%20geht%20*%20nichts%22)

Bei der zweiten Suche gibt es ziemlich viele Treffer, daraus kann man schließen, dass die Redewendung *zumindest* der Umgangssprache angehört.

Die Fragen lauten also:

- **wo bzw. in welchen Dialekten** verwendet man die Redewendung?
- Woraus ist sie entstanden?
- Gibt es andere Fälle, bei denen man `ohne` mit Dativ verwenden kann?

Comment: Ich habe auch im Atlas zur Alltagssprache gesucht, konnte aber nichts dazu finden. http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/liste-aller-varianten/

Comment: Wie bereits in der anderen Frage zum Vorschein kommt, ist ohne + Dativ in Österreich verbreitet. Im Falle von "trotz" wurde das z.B. von B. Sick erwähnt, siehe etwa http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-der-dativ-ist-dem-genitiv-sein-tod-a-267725.html. Auch der Duden liefert dazu einen Hinweis. Direkt zu "ohne" habe ich noch keine Quelle gefunden.

Comment: In meinem "Österreichisches Wörterbuch", 39. Auflage (2005), finde ich dazu keinen Hinweis, die Verwendung des Dativs ist also wohl auch im österreichischen Deutsch nicht korrekt. Die Verwendung in Umgangssprache und Dialekten ist hier (Niederösterreich, Wien) aber nicht unüblich.

Comment: Also in meiner Umgebung (Steiermark) bekommt man das wirklich sehr oft so zu hören. Meine Deutsch-Professorin ist immer ausgerastet wenn sowas in einem Aufsatz vorkam ;)

Answer (score 4):

»Ohne dem« bzw. »ohne der« ist dort, wo ich aufgewachsen bin (Umgebung von Graz bzw. Ost-Steiermark), durchaus gängig, aber diese Floskel gehört ganz klar dem regionalen Dialekt bzw. der mündlichen Umgangssprache an.

Niemand, der die Hochsprache (österreichisches Deutsch) ausreichend gut gelernt hat, wird diese Konstruktion im Kontext der Hochsprache verwenden. Dass Schüler gelegentlich diese Formulierung in Aufsätzen verwenden, ist lediglich darauf zurückzuführen, dass deren Muttersprache eben dieser Dialekt ist und die Hochsprache eigentlich erst wie eine Fremdsprache in der Schule erlernt werden muss.

Ich den folgenden Beispielen habe ich nur die Vokabel aus dem oststeirischen Dialekt ins österreichische Hochdeutsch übersetzt. Die Grammatik habe ich nicht übersetzt, die Beispiele spiegeln also die Grammatik dieses Dialekts wider:

> Männlich: Wo ist mein Mantel? Ohne dem kann ich bei dieser Kälte nicht hinaus.
>   Weiblich: Hast du die ganze Milch ausgetrunken? Ohne der kann ich keine Palatschinken machen.
>   Sächlich: Siehst du mein Auto dort drüben? Ohne dem bin ich nur ein halber Mensch.

Ich lebe übrigens seit knapp 20 Jahren nicht mehr in Graz, sondern im nur 150 km entfernten Wien. Hier habe ich diese Formulierung nur sehr selten gehört.