# Dative vs Accusative

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, accusative

I was doing some dative preposition exercises to familiarize myself with how they use it in german. I came across this sentence

> Ich spreche mit meinem Bruder

Why is it "*mit meinem*" and not "*mit meinen*"? Ain't I speaking directly to my brother?

PS : Just started learning not too long ago.

Comment: So some preposition will always follow either dative or accusation?

Comment: @MunWai Exactly. "mit" is easy to learn. But, for example, why "think about X" means "denken an + Dativ", probably no one can say.

Comment: »Denken an« takes Akkusativ!

Comment: *"speaking **directly** to my brother"* I think I know what the problem is. I bet someone told you about direct and indirect objects. Please forget this concept! It is misleading. It helps only in 90% of all sentences and is wrong in 10%. In German grammar the terms "direktes Objekt" and "indirektes Objekt" doesn't exists. Take any German grammar book and search for those terms: You won't find them. German has dative object, accusative objects, genitive objects, prepositional objects, and some also use the term "nominative object", but there is no direct object. Please forget it and ignore it.

Comment: @Raketenolli Well, "Denken an" can take the dative if the thinker was standing on top of the brother...

Comment: Yes indeed, most resources that I use, explains it by either direct or indirect object. But thank you all for the quick helpful response!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The components of this sentence are:

- **ich**
  subject
  personal pronoun, first person, singular, nominative case
- **spreche**
  predicate
  verb (a form of "sprechen"), first person, singular, present tense
- **mit meinem Bruder**
  prepositional object

---

The verb *sprechen* (to speak, to talk) can have these kinds of objects:

- **accusative object**
  **What** are you speaking? (What is coming out of your mouth when you are speaking?) (Rare: **Who** are you speaking?)

  > Ich spreche **deine Sprache.** (I speak your language.)
  >   Ich spreche **nur den ersten Satz.** (I speak only the first sentence.)
  >   Ich spreche **meinen Bruder.**

  The last sentence is rare and can have two meanings:

  1. I will meet my brother and will have a conversation with him. You use this version often with an additional temporal adverb (*»Morgen spreche ich meinen Bruder und da werden wir dann die weitere Vorgehensweise klären.«* = Tomorrow I will meet my brother and then we will clarify the further course of action.) (This example also shows, that German *Präsens* can be *future tense* in English.)
  2. There is an audio drama about my brother, and in this drama I am speaking the role of my brother.
- **prepositional object with "über"**
  **About who or what** are you speaking? (What is the topic of the conversation?)

  > Ich spreche **über das Wetter.** (I talk about the weather.)
  >   Ich spreche **über das Auto.** (I talk about the car.)
  >   Ich spreche **über meinen Bruder.** (I talk about my brother.)
- **prepositional object with "mit"**
  **With whom** are you talking? (Who is the other participant of the conversation?)

  > Ich spreche **mit dem Lehrer.** (I talk with the teacher.)
  >   Ich spreche **mit der Chefin.** (I talk with the boss.)
  >   Ich spreche **mit meinem Bruder.** (I talk with my brother.)

<sup>*Note, that there are also prepositional objects with other predicates and that you also can have more of them in a sentence, like in this example (I put each prepositional object in square brackets):*</sup>
<sup>*»Der König spricht [während des Festes] [dank der neuen Technik] [durch ein Megaphon] [zu seinem Volk].« = The king speaks [during the festival] [thanks to the new technique] [through a megaphone] [to his people].*</sup>

---

Prepositional objects consists of two parts. The first part is the preposition, and this preposition dictates the grammatical case of the second part:

- **mit** (with)
  always needs **dative** case

  > Ich tanze **mit meiner Tante** (I dance **with my aunt.**)
  >   Er hat sie **mit einem scharfen Messer** erstochen. (He stabbed her **with a sharp knife.**)
  >   Er übt **mit großer Leidenschaft.** (He practices **with great passion.**)

---

These are some frequently used prepositions that always need dative:

> aus, bei, mit, nach, seit

But there are also prepositions that always need accusative:

> durch, für, gegen, ohne, um

Lots of prepositios need genitive case:

> dank, trotz, fern, nördlich, während

And there are also prepositions which can go with dative or accusative, depending on the meaning:

> auf, in, über, vor, zwischen

(Non of the lists is complete.)

Comment: I remember in first classes some sports activity to learn the prepositions for dative with a box and thus your list of prepositions would be dative only - as this site suggests I'm wrong :-o https://www.learn-german-smarter.com/learn-german-prepositions/ - so the location meanings goes to dative

Comment: Just read through, thank you for the informative answer! It was of big help!

Comment: @Shegit Brahm: No. Only for the nine dual-way prepositions dative means location while accusative means direction. For all other prepositions, it's arbitrary.

Comment: Nice list! The fact that "mit" und "ohne" ("with" and "without") require different grammatical cases can be confusing [even for native speakers](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2349/540).

Comment: Just a note that the list of prepositions is not complete (von, gegen, auf ...).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Didn't you read the very last paragraph (the one in brackets)?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Oh, I thought it referred only to the lists of general prepositions preceding it, not to the three possibilities titled "The verb sprechen (to speak, to talk) can have these kinds of objects:" (which sounds exhaustive). After all, there is a horizontal divider. (And I realize that my comment wasn't clear: I mean that "sprechen" can go with all of those, and probably others.)

Comment: @celtschk: Genau das steht bereits in dem kleingedruckten Absatz in der Mitte des Textes

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: OK, das habe ich übersehen (wer liest denn schon das Kleingedruckte? :-))

Comment: @celtschk: Im Kleingedruckten stehen immer die wichtigsten Informationen.